How to protect N-type mosfets in parallel againt back EMF of a transformer
I saw this schematic on a blog and I tried building it but always burns some of my mosfets. I am using the oscillating and driving part of this schematic with the exception of the battery charger part.


Does the circuit instantly die? Or do the MOSFETS heat up rapidly and then fail?

It rapidly heat up and then fail. When tested, some of the mosfets are gone bad and when replaced same thing happens

The Mosfets are IRFP250

Not surprised at all. This circuit was obviously never tested by the author. This is a terrible circuit. Your first-order problem is MOSFET cross-conduction (aka "shoot-through). This means both MOSFET banks are on at the same time shorting each other out. The gate resistors make this worse (larger gate resistor values increase switching time and increase shoot-through duration). No you can't fix that problem by using low value gate resistors (or even eliminating them completely). You need dead-time - a period where both MOSFETS are off. The oscillator chip doesn't have that feature.
What I would do given that you already have the circuit complete, is run one of the outputs of the CD4047 through a "divide-by-4 clock divider". This can be made with a CD4017 IC configured properly. Then use output 1 and output 3 to drive the gates, respectively. This will get you a "modified sine" output and eliminates the deadtime complication. You will also need to increase the oscillator 4 times to compensate.
At this point, your circuit should work. Now back to your original question: Just put rectifiers across the MOSFET's the same way they are shown in the MOSFET symbol. One per bank will be adequate, ideally place close to the transformer.
An additional improvement would be to use gate drivers for the MOSFETs. It's hard to drive them properly at logic levels so your efficiency (and heat generation) suffers.
Also, your circuit will have poor voltage regulation - it's running open-loop.

Sir, can you suggest a working circuit for me please

@KumahAndrews I already suggested what needs to be done to get your circuit working. You can buy Invertors already made for pretty cheap for low power ones. And you can get high quality, high-power ("true sinewave") ones for much more. I don't really know your application and some devices won't like the poor quality AC your circuit (or the low-end commercial grade invertors) produce.

Thank you sir. Much appreciated

You cannot reliably drive those MOSFETs with only 5V.
I suggest adding a pair of gate drivers to start with, using a 10-15V supply. An NPN-PNP emitter follower BJT pair (eg. 2N4401/2N4403) on each output will suffice iff you also increase the supply voltage of the 4047 to 12-15V.
There may be other issues too.
